# The cost of setting up tests in JUnit - using mocked objects versus repository-tests in legacy code

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I work on a project which has existed for many years. The time it takes to build the project with all tests is almost sensational (not in a good way). This is mainly due to a lot of modules, as well as heaps of unit tests which uses a repository to set up test data rather then to mock the desired behaviour. Unit tests using a repository use a lot of time for test setup, and they run quite slowly. This adds up to a lot of time as the system is quite large.

We write all new unit tests by using Mockito to mock the repository (except when we are *actually* testing the repository obviously). We also try to rewrite all existing unit tests to using mocks of the repository instead of an actual repository whenever we have the time and opportunity. Completely eliminating the use of repo's in our tests has a *huge* effect on how much time it takes to run the tests.

A lot of the legacy code sets up its test data by using builders and test-utilities which in turn uses the repository. As the domain is quite complex, this often involves setting up a fair amount of objects and how they are related to each other. Re-writing a class of tests (say ~15 tests) to using only mocked object can therefore be quite time-consuming. And as everywhere else, time is not an infinite resource.

If we are adding some new functionality to a class, it would be far easier to just write one new repository test (in addition to the existing 15) than to find out exactly how the test data needs to be set up by using different mock objects.

I have tried to find some information on how and to what extent the test setup affects the actual time it takes to run the tests, but I have failed to find any useful information. My only "facts" are the observations I make when running a test class. The test setup for a repo test may easily take ~10 seconds, while the test setup for a mocked test class starts in less than a second.

NOTE: I am aware that I can use JUnit Stopwatch to benchmark a single or a set of tests, but my question is more concerned with best practices than exactly how long it takes me to run my tests.

I have two questions:

1. Say I encounter a test class which already has 15 unit tests where none of them mocks any behaviour. I write a test and do a small fix in the class. I do not have the time to re-write the whole test class to mock objects. Should I just add a new test without mocking any behaviour and follow the existing (and bad) pattern? Does it really matter whether I have 15 non-mocked tests and 1 mocked test or if I have 16 non-mocked tests?
2. In my test class with 15 unit tests, some of the tests are easier to refactor than others. Is it worth it to re-write only five of the tests to using mocked objects? Is it against best practice or in any other way not good to have a test class where some of the tests uses mocks and some don't?

Comment: Speaking from experience, using mocks is not conducive to having good tests. And tests that access a database don't have to be too slow. (My current JUnit test suite with 730+ integration tests, lots of db access, less than 1% with any mocking, runs in about 5.5 mins on the Jenkins CI build.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really subjective but I'll try to suggest few options you can explore. It all depends upon how much you're willing to spend.

> Should I just add a new test without mocking any behavior and follow the existing (and bad) pattern? Does it really matter whether I have 15 non-mocked tests and 1 mocked test or if I have 16 non-mocked tests?

Its not about just one new test. If you're still writing in bad/slow pattern, you're just increasing technical debt. You've to lay out the best practices for writing new unit tests yourself.

> In my test class with 15 unit tests, some of the tests are easier to
>   refactor than others. Is it worth it to re-write only five of the
>   tests to using mocked objects?

Absolutely. Why not? You saying for yourself the improvements you're getting by following newer style of code.

> Is it against best practice or in any other way not good to have a
>   test class where some of the tests uses mocks and some don't?
>   Well one best practice is to have consistent code everywhere. Mix of old styled repositories and newer one with mocks does not go too well as far as best practices are concerned. But I'd be more concerned if the code you write is not well covered with unit tests, whatever style if may be.

At the end of the day, you're the one to decide and look at all the trade offs like how much build time improvements can you achieve by newer mocked repositories, what is the frequency of your builds, and can this be achieved using hardware improvements and other factors.

Answer (score 1):

As written by @ShanuGupta there is not general answer to your question.

But here is my thought:

After *correctness* the *readability* is the second most desirable value of code, especially test code (since it is *executable specification*)

On the other hand there is no rule that a unit cannot have more than one Test class. Therefore I'd separate "old" test methods not using mocks from the "mocking" tests by placing them in separate test classes.